# Find the top three highest-paid employees in each department

Tags: sql

I have two tables in my PieCloudDB Database with partial data as follows:

| Id | name | salary | departmentid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cindy | 8500 | 1 |
| 2 | Sam | 6000 | 2 |
| 3 | Mark | 9000 | 1 |
| 4 | Zeus | 8000 | 2 |
| 5 | James | 7000 | 1 |
| 6 | John | 8500 | 1 |
| 7 | Mary | 5000 | 2 |
| 8 | Robert | 6000 | 2 |
| 9 | Randy | 6000 | 1 |

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | IT |
| 2 | Sales |

I want to know who the high earners are in each department. A high earner in a department is defined as an employee whose salary ranks among the **top three different salaries** within that department.

out:

| department | employee | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IT | Mark | 9000 |
| IT | Cindy | 8500 |
| IT | John | 8500 |
| IT | James | 7000 |
| Sales | Zeus | 8000 |
| Sales | Sam | 6000 |
| Sales | Robert | 6000 |
| Sales | Mary | 5000 |

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try using DENSE_RANK() in your PieCloudDB database to make the salary rankings consecutive.

```
SELECT d.name AS Department, e.name AS Employee, e.salary AS Salary 
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY departmentid ORDER BY salary DESC) AS ranking
  FROM Employee
) e
JOIN Department d ON e.departmentid = d.id
WHERE e.ranking <= 3
ORDER BY d.name, e.salary DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @Koa.
Here is another query without the use of ranking.

```
SELECT d.name, e1.name, e1.Salary
FROM employees e1
join department d on e1.department=d.id
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e2.Salary)
    FROM employees e2
    WHERE e2.Department = e1.Department AND e2.Salary > e1.Salary
) < 3 
order by department asc, salary desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the employees and departments tables and filter for employees whose salary is among the top three within their department. Then apply subquery to count the number of distinct salaries for each employees within the same dep.

**Example**

```
SELECT
  d.name AS department,
  e.name AS employee,
  e.salary
FROM employees e
JOIN departments d ON e.departmentid = d.id
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT salary)
  FROM employees e2
  WHERE e2.departmentid = e.departmentid AND e2.salary >= e.salary
) <= 3
ORDER BY department, salary DESC;
```

Result
[image]